# How to handle Nginx internal request or not

Tags: nginx, servlets, lua, proxypass, proxy-server

I use nginx as proxy server and I just set `proxy_intercept_errors on;` and also error_page directive `error_page 400 /400.html; location = /400.html { root /path/to/error; }`.

So the backend server which is tomcat(servlet) sometimes sendError likes `HttpServletResponse.sendError(404);` , that request may come back to nginx and redirect to 400.html.

In this situation I need to handle the internal redirect to 400.

My problem is I use a lua script which is checking some stuff from all income request, so I need to tell my lua to skip check when internal request is come.

Is it possible to identify internal request?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [`proxy_intercept_errors`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) directive?

Comment: @IvanShatsky I am already set `proxy_intercept_errors  on;` so nginx redirect to 400 static html page as I said above something likes internal request, my problem is I need to handle that internal request.

Comment: You don't explain how do you want to handle that request, if you want some custom processing of tomcat 404 response, use [`error_page`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) directive (`error_page 404 ...`).

Comment: @IvanShatsky thanks. Now I edit a lot to my question and improve more information, could you check it again

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly, you need to use [`ngx.req.is_internal()`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqis_internal) function.

Comment: @IvanShatsky thank you very much, you made my day. `ngx.req.is_internal()` is what I am searching for.

Answer (score 0):

The below `ngx.req.is_internal()` is the answer.

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqis_internal